# Could not load type 'Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.Factories.Interfaces.IRenderingFactory'

Tags: sitecore

This issue started, while I installed Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 10.0.0 XP 15.0.1 rev. 201112 while my Sitecore is 10.2, Kindly please suggest or help me with respect to the issue.

Could not load type 'Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.Factories.Interfaces.IRenderingFactory' from assembly 'Sitecore.LayoutService, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.Factories.Interfaces.IRenderingFactory' from assembly 'Sitecore.LayoutService, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

or:

2. Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack trace:

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.Factories.Interfaces.IRenderingFactory' from assembly 'Sitecore.LayoutService, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   Sitecore.LayoutService.GraphQL.RegisterDependencies.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +0
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection() +142
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider() +225
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +513
   Sitecore.Web.Application..cctor() +45

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Web.Application' threw an exception.]
   ASP.global_asax..ctor() +28

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +80
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +182
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated, I am new to sitecore, and not able to find much information on the same, please guide me.

Comment: You can format your Stack Trace output part using angle brackets > for better readability

Comment: Try posting it on Sitecore stack exchange https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This issue is resolved, I tried installing the Sitecore again, copied the bin and appconfig folder, worked well for me, please Note : Its a temporary solution.